# Can “Tentacles” be used for branches?

Tags: word-usage, metaphors

Reading through the following sentence

> It had been my father’s word which had got me a footing in the multinational company which had its tentacles in Asia, Europe and the Middle East.

Oxford languages mean tentacle as:

> 1. a slender, flexible limb or appendage in an animal, especially around the mouth of an invertebrate, used for grasping or moving about, or bearing sense organs.
> 2. (in a plant) a tendril or a sensitive glandular hair.
> 3. something resembling a tentacle in shape or flexibility.
>    "trailing tentacles of vapour"

Can tentacles be used as branches? Is it common?

Edit: The paragraph mentioned by author is as follows.

> My life at Interstar Management had been deceptively easy at the start but that had only been due to my naivety which prevented me from looking past the potential trouble that lurked beneath the surface. My father had worked at Interstar and had been promoted to an overseas posting in Cairo. It had been my father’s word which had got me a footing in the multinational company which had its tentacles in Asia, Europe and the Middle East.

The author had given meaning as branches. Is there any better word to use than tentacles?

Comment: It's not being used as branches here. It's a metaphor for the company being like an octopus whose influence reaches far and wide. (Having your tentacles in something is a very common phrase.) BTW: it should read "tentacles in Asia …"

Comment: @ralph.m updated it to “tentacles in Asia” in the question. noted that it is common phrase.

Comment: Tentacles is usually a negative phrase, implying something malign or sinister, while branches is neutral.

Comment: ... Yes, the octopus/spider metaphor falutes deadlier than the arboreal.

Comment: @ralph.m, in the sentence above, can i take meaning literally as “the company’s feet or legs (branches) are there in Asia, Europe and the  Middle East”

Comment: It's a common phrase, but not a positive one. It has malign connotations for sure.

Comment: @Rachayita — It implies that the company has contacts/influence in those regions in some form, but I don't think it explicitly implies that they have branches there. They might have friends/affiliates etc. or some other form of business relationship.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All of your comments made me learn new perspectives. Thanks for your responses. For this particular sentence, I am going with Stuart F answer and author of my book as “branches”

> Tentacles is usually a negative phrase, implying something malign or sinister, while branches is neutral.